# SSL over tomacat8 and Struts2

Tags: tomcat, ssl, struts2

I've a running server Tomcat 8 with thise connectors:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort='443"/>


<Connector SSLEnabled="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8" clientAuth="false" 
            connectionTimeout="20000" keystoreFile="path" 
            keystorePass="pwd" maxThreads="150" port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

I can that it works because I've got a web app struts1-based on it and the redirection works properly.

I'm developing a new web app with struts2, and it doesn't work. I've done some research and I don't understand if I have to make some changes (settings) on the app (struts.xml, web.xml...) or not, it all relay on Tomcat redirection.

can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping searching I found myself the solution

The http-->https redirection needs only tomcat config; no application setting is needed

Other than the connector in server.xml, add in web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

Source: [here](http://www.journaldev.com/160/steps-to-configure-ssl-on-tomcat-and-setup-auto-redirect-from-http-to-https)